# How to modularize namepace in typescript .d.ts file

Tags: typescript

I have a `index.d.ts`. The main namespace include two namespaces and interfaces that is same name. This is example:

```
// index.d.ts
export = API
export as namespace API

declare namespace API {
  export const val1: any
  export func1(): void

  export namespace Query {}
  export interface Query {}

  export namespace Mutation {}
  export interface Mutation {}
}
```

This sample code is work well. I want to modularize this file. I failed this though I have tried many way. for instance,

```
// index.d.ts
import { Query } from './query.d.ts'
import { Mutation } from './mutation.d.ts'
export = API
export as namespace API

declare namespace API {
  export const val1: any
  export func1(): void

  // pseudocode
  export Query
  export Mutation
}

// query.d.ts
export namespace Query {}
export interface Query {}

// mutation.d.
export namespace Mutation {}
export interface Mutation {}
```

Please help me T^T

Answer (score 0):

`index.d.ts` should be:

```
import { Query as Query1 } from './query'
import { Mutation as Mutation1 } from './mutation'
export = API
export as namespace API

declare namespace API {
  export const val1: any
  export function func1(): void

  export import Query = Query1;
  export import Mutation = Mutation1;
}
```

You use the `import X = Y` syntax to define an alias for an existing symbol (which carries along all its meanings: value, type, and/or namespace) and then export the alias from the `namespace API`.  The tricky part is that you have to originally import `Query` and `Mutation` under alternate names, in my example `Query1` and `Mutation1`, so that you can define aliases with the desired names `Query` and `Mutation` without shadowing the outer `Query` and `Mutation`.  (`export import Query = Query` would be a circular definition; there's no way to explicitly refer to the outer scope.)